# Is it recommended to have more than one condition in my if statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I currently am writing an if statement with a couple of conditions. is there a better or efficient way to write what i have now? Is writing separate if statements better?

```
If (txtNumberOfVehicles.Text = String.Empty OrElse Not IsNumeric(txtNumberOfVehicles.Text) OrElse CInt(txtNumberOfVehicles.Text) < 0) Then
...
End If
```

Comment: purpose of checking is if this textbox. text is not empty and to check if it is a number that is greater than or equal to 0. a validation check. the input cannot be a negative as well

Comment: The OrElse is very efficient. It short=circuits as soon as it hits a false condition. Meaning it stops checking; saves time because not all the conditions need to be checked.

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You wrote it correctly, single `If` command with `OrElse` is good. Do not try to split it to more `if` commands.

I would just remove the first part, because it is redundant. `String.Empty` is not numeric so it will fail in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can look at breaking it down using if and else if, In some cases the select case can also make a lot of sense to you, Ideally every statement should check one condition for proper management. But if all the conditions you are checking end up with the same do action the you can take your chances.